# Lookoing to create a graph based off the average of two columns in my dataset

Tags: python, graph, jupyter-notebook, dataset, data-analysis

Ulitmately I am very new with Data Analysis and am in the middle of a project that is due very soon.

Of the data here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGVBd.png)

I would like to have the Station areas grouped up, and the Time_Diff averaged out for each area.
There are 35000+ entries in this dataset, hence why I want to group it up into the totals so the graph will work.

Such as:

Tallaght: 13:46
Blanchardstown: 14:35
etc..

I have attempted to graph them but my results were only returning the total count of the time_diff column hence making the area with the higher entries the higher count.

The Time_Diff column I made by converting the 'text' value times into datetime using pandas, then minus the IA from the TOC to retrieve the time difference.

My dataset: https://data.gov.ie/dataset/fire-brigade-and-ambulance?package_type=dataset

Brownie points if you can figure out how I can remove the 0 days entry from the output. I believe this was a result of me converting the 'text' to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

subset.groupby('Station Area')['Time_Diff'].mean()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).